# What was the original form of Tonks's Patronus?

Tags: harry-potter

Early in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Harry observes Nymphadora Tonks casting the Patronus Charm:

> As Harry swung the cloak back over himself, she waved her wand; an immense silvery four-legged creature erupted from it and streaked off into the darkness.
>
> "Was that a Patronus?" asked Harry, who had seen Dumbledore
> send messages like this.
>
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Chapter 8 - Snape Victorious)*</sup></sub>

Due to a comment by Snape, Harry determines that Tonks's Patronus must have changed forms recently, and he asks Lupin about it:

> "Tonks’s Patronus has changed its form," he told him. "Snape said so, anyway. I didn’t know that could happen. Why would your Patronus change?"
>
> Lupin took his time chewing his turkey and swallowing before saying slowly, "Sometimes … a great shock … an emotional upheaval …"
>
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Chapter 16 - A Very Frosty Christmas)*</sup></sub>

However, at no point does anyone identify what Tonks's Patronus used to be.

**What form did Tonk's Patronus take before it changed?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only place on this site that had this information was a comment on an answer to a related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172784/59105. I'm self-answering to put it in a more permanent form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pottermore's [article on the Patronus Charm](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm), written by J.K. Rowling, answers this question:

> The form of a Patronus may change during the course of a witch or wizard’s life. Instances have been known of the form of the Patronus transforming due to bereavement, falling in love or profound shifts in a person’s character. Thus Nymphadora Tonks’s Patronus changes from a jack rabbit to a wolf (not a werewolf) when she falls in love with Remus Lupin.

Therefore, Tonks's Patronus Charm took the form of a **jack rabbit**.

Answer (score -1):

J.K rowling confirms that her Patronus changed from a **Jack rabbit** to a wolf on Pottermore. So that means her old Patronus was a **Jack rabbit** .

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to provide the link to the relevant Pottermore page to back this up and include the relevant quote?

Comment: Hey if you could find a link to where you read this it would help re-enforce you answer.

Comment: This answer is no different from Lucas's answer (the accepted one above)...